# Is there an equivalent to pandas pivot_table() function in ML.NET?

Tags: c#, pandas, ml.net

I've just started trying to learn with ML.NET and I have a csv that represents products that a customer purchased, so I have columns for userId and productId. I want to transform this so that I have columns for each product ID and rows for each user, with the value being either 1 or NaN, depending on whether or not they purchased the item. Is this possible with an IDataView in ML.NET? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [CustomMapping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.ml.custommappingcatalog.custommapping?view=ml-dotnet#Microsoft_ML_CustomMappingCatalog_CustomMapping__2_Microsoft_ML_TransformsCatalog_System_Action___0___1__System_String_Microsoft_ML_Data_SchemaDefinition_Microsoft_ML_Data_SchemaDefinition_). You can add columns based on custom logic on other columns, like in the example below IsUnderThirty is added based on the value of Age.

```
 // Get a small dataset as an IEnumerable and convert it to an IDataView.
        var samples = new List<InputData>
        {
            new InputData { Age = 26 },
            new InputData { Age = 35 },
            new InputData { Age = 34 },
            new InputData { Age = 28 },
        };
        var data = mlContext.Data.LoadFromEnumerable(samples);

        // We define the custom mapping between input and output rows that will be applied by the transformation.
        Action<InputData, CustomMappingOutput > mapping =
            (input, output) => output.IsUnderThirty = input.Age < 30;
```

Comment: I don't know if there is or isn't a way to do this with CustomMapping, but the example above from the documentation does not demonstrate it.